# Mapping component attributes without a value

Tags: angular, custom-attributes

I am after providing a property for my Angular component. By property I mean a toggle-style boolean attribute that you put in HTML without specifying the attribute's value:

as opposed to an input (this is not what I want):

If `compact` is present then the component should coerce its value it to a boolean:

1. `<my-component compact="compact">` // <= true
2. `<my-component compact="true>` // <= true
3. `<my-component compact="false">` // <= true?

If `compact` has no value then it maps to true:

4. `<my-component compact>` // <= true

If `compact` is missing out:

5. `<my-component>` // <= false

However when I leave it without an attribute value, the component sees null, so I am not able to distinguish between case #4 and #5, even if I provide a default value within constructor.

```
  constructor(
    @Attribute('compact') public compact,
  ) {
    console.log(this.compact) // `null` for <my-component compact>
  }
```

How should I go about it? Is Attribute decorator alone capable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case #1~4, the type of `compact`'s value will always be string.

In case #4, the value of `compact` is **empty string**(type of `string`) while case #5 will be **null**(type of `object`), so you can distinguish case #4 and #5 by `typeof(compact)`.