# Create Angular component with attribute without value

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template

I've started learning Angular recently one problem very simple (I think) which I can't find a solution is the following one:

I want to create a Component with a custom attribute without a value.
Like this one:

```html
<h1 attribute-without-value > Text <h1>
```

I tried in a different way but still, I don't have what I want.
I'm able to create an attribute with a value using this syntax: `[attr.attr-with-value]="value"` but not without.
Here some of my experiment (ref: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sn94cl?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts):

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:  `
              <h1 {{nameAttr}} > doesn\'t work <h1>
              <h1 [attr.nameAttr] > also this doesn\'t work <h1>
              `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  nameAttr = 'attribute-without-value';
}
```

How can I do?

Comment: I guess the question is; why?

Comment: Your original code `<h1 attribute-without-value >` should work and add the attribute, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wamvpd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.html). Do you need the attribute name to be dynamic?

Comment: yes I want it dynamic :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are actually looking for [directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) not components

Answer (score 0):

The string interpolation {{}} should be placed inside the text area of the h1 element.

```
<h1> {{nameAttr}} <h1>
```

If you don't want it to have a value, you can just set nameAttr to '' or null.

Or if you're trying to pass a value INTO a component without a value, then you'll have to create a 2nd component, one you can pass the data to.
[Mapping component attributes without a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49026154/mapping-component-attributes-without-a-value)

Comment: I want a dom element with an attribute not an element with `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

Try a directive. The way you try to do it it won't work.

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives